# mysql getting max value of a column group by many

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql table:

```
id       int
a        varchar
b        varchar
c        varchar
version  int
active   bool
```

I want to grab the max version group by a, b and c , so I have following query to do that:

```
select a, b, c, max(version) as version from mytbl where active = 1 group by (a, b, c)
```

but this returns

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis in your group by - group by a,b,c

Answer (score 4):

Your group by syntax is wrong, it should look like this:

```
group by a, b, c
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove open & close brackets after group by .it should be

```
select a, b, c, max(version) as version from mytbl where active = 1 group by a, b, c
```